# Equivalent for str.decode('string_escape')

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7

What is the equivalent for `str.decode('string_escape')` in javascript?

```
data = {'k':'test\"ing\:"'}
json.dumps(data).decode('string_escape')
>>> '{"k": "test"ing""}'
```

Comment: Why would you ever want to decode like that?

Comment: I want to render it on a textarea which should not have \".

Comment: Why does it have `\"` in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary in JavaScript.

```
var j1 = JSON.stringify({foo:1, bar:"baz"});
// "{"foo":1,"bar":"baz"}"
JSON.parse(j1)
// Object { foo=1, bar="baz"}

var j2 = JSON.stringify({'k':'test\"ing\:"'})
// "{"k":"test\"ing:\""}"
JSON.parse(j2)
// Object { k="test"ing:""}
```

Comment: I meant, not parsing & unparsing JSON string. string_escape replaces all escaped literals to actual literal.  eg: \n - new line, \" - ", \t - tab

Comment: Then please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28562189/edit) and add an example that includes these characters.